# UWP Certification - App Store Signing ( issue - can't sign Store Builds ) - Sideload Builds Sign - no issue

Tags: c#, uwp, certificate, cert

I'm trying to sign an App Store Build.
Local ( side loaded builds do sign w/ password ).

A message comes up during build to hit OK / Cancel and to Add new Certificate ( should be there already ) and hitting Ok ( you can enter password and get a missing Criteria/Container error ). If you hit Cancel there isn't a prompt and the Signing Process is cancelled.

Visual Studio 17.7.1 <---- (Updated)

My Certificate store is also getting loaded with Certificates with a GUID as a CN ( 20+ of these ! ).

Also, using the MSIX Tool will NOT Sign with the .CER.
Anyone know what the issue is or any fixes ?

Using Token/USB

Thanks !

Tried removing Client Software
Tried re-booting OS / IDE
Tried Signing with MSIX Tool
Tried installing a CERT from my Token.

( once again local builds can and are able to sign - Sideload Build ).

Answer (score -1):

Added Certificate Keeps displaying in Visual Studio for Store Release : ( have USB Key for Signing ).

[ FOR STORE RELEASE - UWP ]

In the .csproj file change this tag below for Project while having .NET Native Compile checked in build properties. ( must have it checked for Store build now - not sure about past ).

( Answering my own question here ).

GenerateTemporaryStoreCertificate to False PropertyGroup.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).